# Como mudar o CSS do Datepicker?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Observe a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu HTML;

```
 <input  class="form-control date-picker"  placeholder="Data Início">
```

E esse é meu código Javascript;

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM/yy',
       // dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        nextText: 'Proximo',
        prevText: 'Anterior'
    });
});
```

1. Por favor, como faço  para mudar a cor do calendário para Azul?
2. E como eu faço para aparecer os nome dos meses, pois está em branco?

Comment: Oi, você pode criar uma folha de estilo complementar e fazer uso do inspetor de elementos do navegador para visualizar a árvore de estilos e modificá-las ou arriscar a mudança do arquivo original, o que não é aconselhável, crie uma nova folha e chame-a após a do plugin e faça suas modificações.

Comment: Cara coloca o plugin que vc está usando ai. só com essas infos não da para te responder... Aqui por eemplo está ficando assim http://prntscr.com/ndb82y e vc usa Bootstrap 3 ou 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jQuery possui uma página onde você pode montar o tema que quiser para o componente (escolhendo as cores etc.)

O link é este: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Como você quer alterar apenas o Datepicker, é só alterar as opções na caixa à esquerda da página e ir visualizando como fica (na página irá aparecer vários componentes. Mas ou menos no meio da página você vai ver o Datepicker):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se não quiser ter trabalho de ficar alterando as opções, na página de download do tema, existem vários temas pré-configurados, onde você pode selecionar o que mais lhe agradar.

É só clicar em "Download theme" e no fim da página você verá um select com uma lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antes de baixar um tema pré-configurado, você pode visualizá-los nesta página:

https://www.plus2net.com/jquery/msg-demo/date-picker-themes.php

Após baixar o tema, descompacte o .zip e inclua o arquivo `jquery-ui.theme.css` ou `jquery-ui.theme.min.css` (compactado) na sua página.